# How to use 'yield' to return a sequence of results of a function?

Tags: python, list, generator, yield, n-queens

I'm learning to use 'yield'. Our professor asked us to solve the N-Queens problem using 'yield'. My function could work out correct solutions but I just don't know how to use 'yield' to return these solutions.

Here's my code (in which 'board' is a one-dimensional list):

```
def n_queens_valid(board):
# to decide if a position is allowed
    if len(board) != len(set(board)):
        return False

    for x in range(len(board)-1):
        for y in range(x+1,len(board)):
            if abs(y-x) == abs(board[x]-board[y]):
                return False
    return True


def n_queens_helper(n,board):
# to generate solutions
    if len(board) == n:
        print(board)
        yield copy.deepcopy(board) ############
    for queen in range(n):
        board.append(queen)
        if n_queens_valid(board):
            n_queens_helper(n, board) 
        board.pop()

solutions = n_queens_helper(4,[])
list(solutions)
```

If the yield statement is removed, function `n_queens_helper(n,board)` will be able to print all the solutions. However with the yield statement the final result is going to be `[]`.

Could anybody help me with this problem?

***Additional information***
I'm using python 3.6 ! And here's the code that could print the results:

```
def n_queens_valid(board):
    if len(board) != len(set(board)):
        return False

    for x in range(len(board)-1):
        for y in range(x+1,len(board)):
            if abs(y-x) == abs(board[x]-board[y]):
                return False
    return True


def n_queens_helper(n,board):
    if len(board) == n:
        print(board)
    for queen in range(n):
        board.append(queen)
        if n_queens_valid(board):
            n_queens_helper(n, board) 
        board.pop()

n_queens_helper(7,[])
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Please post your original working code that doesn't use `yield`.

Comment: One issue is that you are calling `n_queens_helper(n, board)` but you are throwing away the result, which means it does nothing (the generator is actually run only when you try to iterate over it). Try to add `yield from n_queens_helper(n, board)`. Or use `for result in n_queens_helper(n, board): yield result` if you are using python<3.3. I'm not sure whether this is the only issue in your code, as such I'm not posting this as an answer.

Comment: Made some edits just now. Sorry for not making it clear enough!

Comment: Are you sure this is the part of code where you want to insert yield?

Comment: I guess it is :(